# ignoring saturday and sunday

Tags: date, mysql

I am pulling in all the records from my customer database(mysql) for the last ten days
    $offset1 =strtotime("-10 day");
         $date3=date("Y-m-d",$offset1);

SELECT * FROM customers WHERE date between '$date3' and '$date' AND customer.custid = '$custid' ORDER by date DESC

I would like to leave out the dates falling on a saturday or sunday and would like to put this in my query rather than the php

If you can help thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `DayOfWeek` function from MySQL.

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
WHERE date between '$date3' and '$date'
      AND DayOfWeek(date) <> 1
      AND DayOfWeek(date) <> 7
      AND customer.custid = '$custid' 
ORDER by date DESC
```

Comment: You might play with how to express the bound check on that to see if you can find a way to remove the pair of checks: `DayOfWeek(date) % 7 > 1`. As always, *benchmark* this as it is harder to read and the engine might do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the DAYNAME function:

```
AND DAYNAME(date) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
```

[DAYNAME(date)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname)